# memory read failed for 0x600000000

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

i am doing my simple C language practice on xcode Mac

this is simple bubble sort algorithm.

i guess there is no logical or grammar error in the codes
but i see the error warning after debugging

error: memory read failed for 0x600000000

maybe this is about memory problem but i don't know what it means about 
and how i can solve this problem without any warning messages

P.S: i am not native english speaker. Thank you for understanding my poor english in advance :)

```
int p[]={0},i,j,num,temp;

printf("number: ");
scanf("%d",&num);

for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    scanf("%d",&p[i]);

printf("arry numbers show-----");
printf("\n");
for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    printf("%d ",p[i]);
printf("\n");

for(i=0;i<num;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<num-1;j++)
    {
        if(p[j]>p[j+1])
        {
            temp=p[j];
            p[j]=p[j+1];
            p[j+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}

for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    printf("%d ",p[i]);
printf("\n");
```

Comment: `p` has only one element(`int p[]={0}`).

Comment: This: `int p[]={0}` will create an array of size 1 that contains a single element, 0. The array is a C array and will not grow after that. You could create a variable-length array (VLA) of size `num` _after_ scanning `num` or allocate enough space when the actual size of the array is known.

Comment: alright . i got it now . i thought C array could grow up . Thank you very much oehm !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have explicitly initialized array `int p[]={0}` with only one element. In case of sorting if you have only one element that means it is already sorted! See this documentation of Arrays [Arrays documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/).

Comment: thank you for your valuable feedback  ! im gonna check out the link